Next.js CORS issue regarding Signal R connection
I have configured a Signal R connection in my next.js component.
import { useState } from 'react';
import { HubConnectionBuilder } from '@microsoft/signalr';
import { useGlobalState } from '@/context/GlobalStateContext';


interface ConfigProps {
    config: Config
}
export interface Config {
    connect: boolean
}

const SignalRComponent: React.FC<ConfigProps> = ({config}) => {
    const [connected, setConnected] = useState<boolean>(false);

    const { state, dispatch } = useGlobalState();

    const connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
    .withUrl(`${state.config.url}/${state.config.endpoint}/${state.config.gamingserver}-${state.config.playerid}`) // Replace with your SignalR hub URL
    .build();
    
    const connect = async () => {
        try {
            await connection.start();
            setConnected(true);
            connection.on("ReceiveMessage", (user: string, message: string) => {
                console.log(`${user}: ${message}`);
            });
            console.log("Connected to SignalR");
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(`${state.config.url}/${state.config.endpoint}/${state.config.gamingserver}-${state.config.playerid}`)

        }
    };

    const disconnect = async () => {
        try {
            await connection.stop();
            setConnected(false);
            console.log("Disconnected from SignalR");
        } catch (err) {
            console.error("Error disconnecting from SignalR", err);
        }
    };

    return (
        <>
            {
                config.connect ? (<button className='bg-green-200 hover:bg-green-300 text-green-800 font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded' type="submit" onClick={connect}>Connect</button>) 
                : (<button className='bg-red-200 hover:bg-red-300 text-red-800 font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded' onClick={disconnect}>Disconnect</button>)
            }                        
        </>
    );
};

export default SignalRComponent;


The withUrl value is input in the form by the user meaning it is dynamic.
When trying to establish a connection I am getting a CORS error

Access to fetch at 'https://example.co.za/testing/332-4255/negotiate?negotiateVersion=1' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

The issue is not with the server, I have checked.
I have tried the middlewre approach but it is not working, any clue on how to fix this?

example.co.za is the one who would have to allow this request. Are you in charge of that site/endpoint?

Looks like a typical CORS issue. Since you're confident the server is set up correctly, here are a couple of things to try:

Proxy through Next.js: Set up an API route in Next.js to proxy requests and avoid CORS. Something like this:



// pages/api/proxy.ts
export default async (req, res) => {
  const response = await fetch(`https://example.co.za/${req.query.endpoint}`, {
    method: req.method,
    headers: {
      ...req.headers,
      'Origin': undefined // remove the origin header
    },
    body: req.body
  });
  const data = await response.json();
  res.status(response.status).json(data);
};




Set withCredentials: true when building the connection in case your server requires it:



const connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
  .withUrl(url, { withCredentials: true })
  .build();



